Do we have to set boundary at $0$?
Hi all I have a fundamental question about heat equation, so far all the heat equation set up I have experienced asasume boundary at a boundary at $x=0$, (assuming it's one-dimensional). I'm wondering what may happen if I say boundary is $x=1$ for example (the domain is $x>1, t>0$). Will that change the solution? I have this question when dealing with the moving boundary problem, that a boundary is moving in space with time, in that case, do we have to make sure that the boundary initially starts at $x=0$?
Another example is assuming heat transfer in a semi-infinite rod and the end of that rod is usually treated as $x=0$. If we know temperature $x=1$ which is the interior of a rod then solving backward for Temperature at $x=0$ is ill-posed problem. But what if we treat $x=1$ as a new boundary and does that make the problem well-posed?

The heat equation is invariant with respect to spatial translations: if $u(x,t)$ solves $u_t - u_{xx} = 0$, and $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ is a constant, then you can easily verify that $v(x,t) = u(x-x_0,t)$ solves $v_t - v_{xx} = 0$. Of course, if $u$ satisfies a boundary condition as well, then $v$ will satisfy a shifted version of that boundary condition. So regarding your first question, the answer is that for a problem with a fixed boundary, you may perform a change of variable to translate the location of the boundary to any other fixed location. For a problem involving a moving boundary this no longer applies, as $u(x-g(x,t),t)$ will not in general solve the heat equation.
